# Yii - php warning: creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, yii

I am new to PHP an YII framework don't be strict.
I have some code that gets from google currency exchenge rate.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
     {
         $model = WidgetCurrencyElement::model()->findByPk($i);

         $buy = 100.25*$er[$i];
         $buy = (int)$buy;
         $buy /= 100;

         $sale = $er[$i]/0.010025;
         $sale = (int)$sale;
         $sale /= 100;

         $model->buy = $buy;
         $model->sale = $sale;

         if(!$model->save()){
             print_r($model->getErrors());
             die("not saved!");
         }
     }
     $this->render('currency', array('er1' => $er[1], 'er2'=>$er[2], 'er3'=>$er[3]));
}
```

and it shows me

"PHP warning Creating default object from empty value". I can't understand why.
What is the reason of this kind of error?
The '$model' is not tottaly empty.

Comment: findByPk($i) is looping through for so do you all ids(1,2,3) available in database

Comment: reason should be that one or more of the ids not in db. Instead of finding items in a loop like this, it would be better to run one query and then loop through the results to bypass issues like this.

Comment: @YatinMistry you were right, the third id was missing, so I did as arkoad 
pointed me in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Arkoak said, probably one or more id is not exist in database. So it's better to make sure object existence after finding it, then try to assign value to it:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++)
 {
     $model = WidgetCurrencyElement::model()->findByPk($i);
     if($model != null)
     {
         $buy = 100.25*$er[$i];
         $buy = (int)$buy;
         $buy /= 100;

         $sale = $er[$i]/0.010025;
         $sale = (int)$sale;
         $sale /= 100;

         $model->buy = $buy;
         $model->sale = $sale;

         if(!$model->save()){
             print_r($model->getErrors());
             die("not saved!");
         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: Thank's a lot! Your answer helped me. I spend two hours for fixing that warning.